# Why is the col-Offset not working for a content box?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, offset

http://www.bootply.com/YhsxilAlOB#

On line 8 I am trying to center the red outlined box by using bootstrap's offset. It reads 
`class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4"`
Im a little confused.  Why is it not working? It does in other places.

Answer (score 0):

**Delete** `margin:50px 0px 50px 0px` in

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" 
style="background-color:rgba(255,255,255, 0.5); margin:50px 0px 50px 0px; border:solid 1px red;">
```

That's the reason why it is not working.